# Outlook Addin - authorization to graph api

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to get content of mailbox attachment in backend<->backend flow. But reading the docs of Outlook REST API will be depracted soon. To future proof from that I would like to swap to graph API.

So far I used token got from: Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true })

But this one is not working for graph API (at least I couldn't make it work).

How can I achieve similar thing with graph API, but without forcing user to additionally login to aquire graph API token?

Answer (score 0):

getAccessToken is an option here to get a graph token. The API There are extra steps involved, but does not require additional login for user. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph

If getAccessToken does not work for your scenario, it would be helpful to know why or more about your use case. There isn't a direct Office JS API that allows you to get the token that can be used against Graph. The getCallbackToken with isRest true only returns a token that can be used against REST. We also track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.